# Only one route redirects to a trailing slash

Tags: php, laravel

So I have a route:

```
Route::get('dashboard', 'Dashboard\DashboardController@index');
```

And when I try to open this route a trailing slash is added and I am being redirected to a 404 error. this: /dashboard becomes this /dashboard/

And the strangest thing is that is happening with ONLY the dashboard route, All other routes are working just fine.

```
Route::get('dashboard/users', 'Dashboard\UsersController@index');
Route::get('dashboard/users/create', 'Dashboard\UsersController@create');
Route::post('dashboard/users/create', 'Dashboard\UsersController@store');
Route::get('dashboard/users/edit/{id}', 'Dashboard\UsersController@edit');
Route::post('dashboard/users/edit/{id}', 'Dashboard\UsersController@update');
Route::get('dashboard/users/delete/{id}', 'Dashboard\UsersController@destroy');
```

all these and all other routes work fine

any suggestion is welcome

Comment: yes i know that, I like my routes like this. but that is not my issue. as described in the post. only one route gets a slash added at the end all other routes work fine

Comment: Try open page in incognito (private) mode and check if you get this same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was obvious. I just missed it.

I had a folder under the public folder with the same name as my route and the .htaccess clearly states:

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
```

So if anyone else comes across this issue just check that you dont have a folder under the public that has the same name as a route.

Answer (score 1):

It is intentional.

In their [.htaccess](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess) file, you can read the following snippet:

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Wich does the redirection (Line 8 in the current version).

If you dont want it to redirect, just comment those lines.

Comment: All my routes work perfectly normal, and the htaccess is a usual .htacces which cuts off the trailing slash at the end. That is the problem. in my case ONE ROUTE is being added a slash at the end and its not being cut off. all other routes work as expected

Comment: I had the same issue with my dev server, just comment those lines and it will be ok...